# Get values from Excel

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the values from the Excel from the selected range. It works fine if there are no merged cells but it does not return the value of merged cells. Is there any way to get both the values of merged and normal cells in one iteration using C#.

```
int lastrowcount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
Excel.Range newrange = xlWorksheet.get_Range(SearchOnColumn + "1",
                                  SearchOnColumn + lastrowcount);
var foundCell = newrange.Find(Text, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

`foundcell` only gives the value of normal cells not the merged one.

Answer (score 0):

Merged cells in excel are read by their first cell address. You should be able to pick up merged cell B2:E2 as B2

Comment: Yes it works if I send the cell address but what I want to do is choose the range and get all the values from that range no matter if it has merged cells or not.

Comment: So what is your question exactly then? Do you need to determine if you range contains merged cells? How to skip a merged cell? If you can clarify, then I can probably help :)

Comment: For example if I select the range from B1 to B50 ,I want to get all the values . I am getting the values of normal cells but not the merged cells.

Comment: So you need to determine if a cell is merged or not, and then take special action. Have you looked at the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.merge.aspx